# Extract a price with commas as thousand separators after dollar sign

Tags: python, regex

The string I have is

```
SECURE to Lender the repayment of the indebtedness evidenced by Borrower's note dated 01/18/2006 and extensions and renewals thereof (herein Note"), in the principal sum of U.S.$155,000.00, with interest thereon, providing for monthly installments of principal and interest, with the balance of the indebtedness, if not sooner paid, due and payable on 01/23/2036.
```

I have tried and found some of the keywords but cant get amount no.

```
("((Account No[.]: )[\d]+)|(?=((?!, of|, among ).)*?the Trustor, )(((?!, of|, among ).)+)", data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
\$\d+(?:,\d+)*                           # price with commas as thousand sep
\$\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?                 # with optional fractional part
\$(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)\b(?:\.\d+)? # a more precise x,xxx,xxx(.xxx)? format
```

Or, if the `$` is always preceded with `U.S.`:

```js
\bU\.S\.\$\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lNpU4m/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5CbU%5C.S%5C.%5C%24%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%2B)*(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F):

[image]

*Details*:

- `\bU\.S\.\$` - `U.S.$` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a comma and one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits.